# Kd-Tree Question

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, kdtree

I am trying to implementation and understand `KdTree`, Following is the link I found.
http://ldots.org/kdtree/#buildingAkDTree
But I fail to understand following algorithm

```
tuple function build_kd_tree(int depth, set points):
    if points contains only one point:
        return that point as a leaf.

    if depth is even:
        Calculate the median x-value.
        Create a set of points (pointsLeft) that have x-values less than
            the median.
        Create a set of points (pointsRight) that have x-values greater
            than or equal to the median.
    else:
        Calculate the median y-value.
        Create a set of points (pointsLeft) that have y-values less than
            the median.
        Create a set of points (pointsRight) that have y-values greater
            than or equal to the median.

    treeLeft = build_kd_tree(depth + 1, pointsLeft)
    treeRight = build_kd_tree(depth + 1, pointsRight)

    return(median, treeLeft, treeRight)
```

I do not understand what is the meaning of 
`Calculate the median x-value.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `points` have `x` and `y` values. The [median](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Median) of `x` values can be obtained by sorting by `x`, then taking the middle element's `x` (for an odd number of `points`) or the mean of the two middle `points`' `x` (for an even number of `points`).

Alternatively, use a fast [selection algorithm](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Selection_algorithm) such as median-of-medians.

Comment: what happens when the algorithm recurse , should it removed the element which is inserted and take median of remaining values.

Comment: @Avinash: obviously yes, since in the recursive calls you're dealing with a different set of `points`.

Comment: thanks, One more doubt, This seems to be dealing with static set of data points, is there different algorithm for data points which are not known during building a tree.

Comment: @Avinash: you mean adding elements to the tree in an online fashion? I believe there are, google something like "kd-tree nearest neighbor online learning".